# Цифры в числе. Дано число, необходимо вывести два числа через пробел

Tags: java, циклы

Дано число, необходимо вывести два числа через пробел. Первое число - количество нечетных цифр данного числа, второе число - произведение четных цифр данного числа. Если четных цифр в числе нет - произведение 0.

Вроде все как надо написал, но почему-то не проходит проверку...в чем моя ошибка?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int a = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt(), c = 0, x = 1;
    while(a > 0){
        int b = a%10;
        if(b%2 == 0)
            x *= b;
        if(b%2 != 0)
            c++;
        a /= 10;
    }
    System.out.printf("%d %d", c, x);
}
```

Comment: Напоминаю, что вы [можете отметить ответ как принятый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.out.printf("%d %d", c, (x == 1)? 0 : x);
```